# jQuery buttons appears too big

Tags: jquery, css

I use jQuery buttons on my site and the buttons are too big compared to the text size. I know a solution which consist of setting the font size width on the body tag like this:

```
body
{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

**But all my fonts will be smaller and I only want my jQuery buttons to be smaller.**

Any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Set the font size on the button elements only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this your css. Make sure you include this css after jquery-ui css.

```
.ui-button .ui-button-text {
  font-size:63.5% /* or whatever you want.*/
```

}